# How to filter a List of Map for creating another List of Map as the result of a search functionality

Tags: list, flutter, dart, search

I am trying to implement a search function in my app for filtering between many entries in a list of map.

The data structure that I have is:

```
[{Entry: Accident , Definition: An unexpected event or circumstance without deliberate intent.}, {Entry: Accident Insurance , Definition: Insurance for unforeseen bodily injury.}, {Entry: Accident Only , Definition: An insurance contract that provides coverage, singly or in combination, for death, dismemberment, disability, or hospital and medical care caused by or necessitated as a result of accident or specified kinds of accident.}, {Entry: Accident Only or AD&D , Definition: Policies providing coverage, singly or in combination, for death, dismemberment, disability, or hospital and medical care caused by or necessitated as a result of accident or specified kinds of accidents. Types of coverage include student accident, sports accident, travel accident, blanket accident, specific accident or accidental death and dismemberment (ad&d).} ... etc, etc.  ]
```

These are the contents of the .json file:

```
[
        {
            "Entry": "Accident ",
            "Definition": "An unexpected event or circumstance without deliberate intent."
        },
        {
            "Entry": "Accident Insurance ",
            "Definition": "Insurance for unforeseen bodily injury."
        },
        [... and looooots of many other "Entry", "Definition" pairs like these]
        {
            "Entry": "Written Premium ",
            "Definition": "The contractually determined amount charged by the reporting entity to the policyholder for the effective period of the contract based on the expectation of risk, policy benefits, and expenses associated with the coverage provided by the terms of the insurance contract."
        }
]
```

Each map entry creates one button with an associated definition.

The user is queried for a search query to get only the button(s) that satisfy the query result.

I include the .dart file that I am trying to implement:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'listentries.dart';
import 'destination.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class searchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String searchTerm;
  searchScreen({this.searchTerm});

  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => new _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<searchScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final widgetElements = new ListEntries(); // From listentries.dart
    var searchedItems =
        widgetElements; // Copy from widgetElements filter out from here
    var query;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(
          "Search your term",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (query) {
                  //search is done here
                  //  filterSearchResults(query);
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search',
                  hintText: 'Search your term',
                  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                    .loadString('assets/data.json'),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  var entries = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

                  final item = entries.where((e) => e['Entry'] == 'Accident'); //Accident will be changed with query
                  print(item);
                  print(entries);

                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      var entrada = entries[index];
                      //print(entrada);

                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: 60,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Destination(
                                  entry: entrada['Entry'],
                                  definition: entrada['Definition'],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          color: Colors.blue[900],
                          child: Text(
                            entrada['Entry'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: entries == null ? 0 : entries.length,
                  );
                },
              ),
              //child: searchedItems,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The issue that I am seeing is that the filtered result (item) is empty and it should contain the entry related to "Accident".

Could you give a hand for the implementation of this search functionality?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Since your problem seems to be related to `final item = entries.where((e) => e['Entry'] == 'Accident');`, try to narrow down the description and code sample of your question.
`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stripped down code sample describing how to filter the items:

```
final List<Map<String, String>> items = [
  {'Entry': 'Accident', 'Definition': 'Accident description.'},
  {'Entry': 'Accident Insurance', 'Definition': 'Insurance description.'},
];
void main() {
  final results = items.where((item) => item['Entry'] == 'Accident');
  print(results);
  // Iterable<Map<String, String>> ({Entry: Accident, Definition: An unexpected event or circumstance without deliberate intent.})
  final result = results.first;
  print(result);
  // Map<String, String> {Entry: Accident, Definition: An unexpected event or circumstance without deliberate intent.}
}
```

Note that `where` returns an Iterable. You can use `toList()` to get a List of Maps.

---

Here is a Flutter sample application closer to what you did before:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyWidget()));

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future:
            DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/entries.json'),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final items = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
          final result =
              items.where((item) => item['Entry'] == 'Accident').first;
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text('Accident Definition:'),
              Text(result['Definition']),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The JSON File I used is here:

```
[
  {
    "Entry": "Accident",
    "Definition": "Accident description."
  },
  {
    "Entry": "Accident Insurance",
    "Definition": "Insurance description."
  }
]
```

Comment: Something very weird happens because when I use the code you include in Android Studio, the result that I get in "results" is empty.  If I use the code you include in the dart pad of https://dart.dev/#try-dart it works as expected.   How can this be possible?  Depending on where you put the code it works or it doesn't work... this puzzles me a lot!

Comment: I have found what is the difference: The data structure that I get from  json.decode(snapshot.data.toString()); is a List<dynamic>, not a List<Map<String, String>>'  I need to be able to filter from the output of json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

Comment: Could you give an example of filtering for the output of json.decode(snapshot.data.toString()); that is a List<dynamic>  ?

Comment: Another possibility is to convert a List<dynamic> to a List<Map<String, String>> and in this case your code will work.

Comment: What is the content of your JSON file?
I added a Flutter Sample Application with a JSON File.

Comment: I have included the .json file

Comment: With the change you included, now I am getting this error:  'Bad state: No element'.  This happens because there is nothing returned from the entries.where(...) statement.  There is an underlying issue related to types

Comment: Did you try my standalone dart sample? Does it work? Can you provide a standalone dart sample reproducing your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228084/discussion-between-pedro-santangelo-and-thierry).

Answer (score 0):

add `.toList()` to create new list

```dart
final item = entries.where((e) => e['Entry'] == 'Accident').toList();
```